# Multiplication Assignment operator doesn't honor mathematical precedence

Tags: c#, .net

For example:

```
//Does NOT honor the rules of Math precedence
Int32 value=10;
value*=15 + 12;  //value=170


//Does honor the rules of Math precedence, and does the multiplication on the second line BEFORE the addition
Int32 value=10;
value=value * 15 + 12; //value=162
```

The first one I would have hoped would have worked correctly, and the compiler would have done the * first, but it didn’t. This is expected, because the * is on the left side to the assignment operator. Is there any way I can create another operator that operates like the ++ and – operators, kinda like this…

```
public Int32 =*(Int32 lhs , Int32 rhs)
{
     //Using the above values 
     lhs=lhs*rhs
}
```

Operation and =* that would have the * on the right hand side, thus being a clear indicator that the * before the assignment operator is reached.  I am just not sure how to break the rhs variable into pieces BEFORE it is evaluated.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: I am pretty sure I can do it in .NET Assemby, but that will just get overwritten each time I recompile.

Comment: interesting question, on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index#assignment-and-lambda-operators) it is stated the operator has higher precedence than the next section and lower precedence than the previous section (right-to-left). which means the addition will be done before the multiplication followed by the assignment - `i = i * (15 + 12)`.

Comment: Yes, but the right hand side is evaluated with correct rules of math operator precedence, then that result is multiplied by the value of the left and side and then assigned to the value, which is not correct. Multiplication takes higher precedence than addition.  It’s a flaw, but only kind of a flaw.  If they created behavior like =* then it would make a lot more sense.  Kind of like the difference between ++variable and variable++ (aka early increment or late increment).

Comment: You are making an incorrect application of operator precedence: the opreator `*` is applied before the operator `+` in an expression, but the operator `=` and the operator `*=` are applied after the basic math operators `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`, hence the rhs is evaluated, then `*=` uses that. That is the definition in C# - operator evaluation is not a textual substitution (like a C pre-processor macro). Note that operator `*=` and operator `*` are not the same operator.

Comment: If `*=` had higher precedence, then the expression is `(value *= 15) + 12;` so what do you think the `+12` would mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense if you're hoping to change the precendence of the `*=` operator.

If I started with this (ignoring the fact that it's not valid C#):

```
Public Int32 =*(Int32 lhs , Int32 rhs)
{
     //Using the above values 
     Return (10*15) + 12;
}
```

... and then had this code:

```
Int32 value = 10;
value =* 15 + 12;
```

... the call to `=*` would set `lhs` as `10`, but it **would have to** set `rhs` as the result of `15 + 12`.

And that would simply be the same behaviour of the built-in `*=` operator.

Comment: It’s pseudo code, and I wrote in it an email to Jon Skeet, not studio. I think you might understand what I want to do, but only maybe. I tested it in studio but wanted to express the issue more than copy my code from studio.

Comment: @BugsBunny - Please show real code whenever possible. Expressing ideas with pseudo code is often misleading.

Comment: While completely correct, this might be better as a comment? :)

Comment: @JoshNoe - Why?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because this doesn't answer the question. It only comments on a mistake made in the question. I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: @JoshNoe - I was trying to illustrate that to pass a single value (i.e. `Int32 rhs`) that the compiler must evaluate before calling the overload. There's no way for the compiler to get around this. You'd have to modify the compiler to get this functionality to work the way that the OP requested it.

Comment: Ah ok I get it. This makes perfect sense now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Based on further comments by OP in the comment section of question, the operator was probably created to make it easier to write the aggregate operations : `sum = sum + value`, and so does not follow the normal mathematical rules, it is probably more useful then what you propose.

C# you cannot create new operator. The existing operators are built into the language, so to add any new one's at a minimum you would also want to implement some parts in compiler to parse them.

C# does allow operator overloading, but then it leads to defining your own integers and I don't think that is a happy road to go down.

There are languages other then C# which do allow this (notably functional languages where operators are just normal methods).

From [C# language specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions)

> Certain operators can be overloaded. Operator overloading permits
>   user-defined operator implementations to be specified for operations
>   where one or both of the operands are of a user-defined class or
>   struct type (Operator overloading).

Comment: I can do it in .NET Assembly I am sure, but fix would be overwritten each compile. This is a perfect reason why all .NET Framework class should be labeled partial. LOL

Comment: That's the reason I mentioned that it would involve rewrite of some parts of compiler

Comment: Of course they can.  I want to create a NEW operator that evaluates correctly with the rules of math operator precedence, not overload an existing one.

Comment: Agreed, and I can do that, but was hoping there was an easier way that one of you could think of.

Comment: Maybe I can create a post compile event that adds then assembly into the IL.  That’s all I can think.